# Popup form closing when form children elements clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a simple popup form which closes when a click event occurs outside the form; however, clicking on any of the forms children elements also closes the popup. Do I need to add the label and input elements to the 'if' statement in the JS function?

HTML

```
    <button id="contactButton" onclick="show()">Contact</button>
    <div id="main">

    <div id="formDiv">
        <form action="" id="form" method="POST">
            <label id="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
function show() {
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
mainDiv.style.display= "block";
mainDiv.addEventListener("click", hide);
}

function hide(e) {
   let targetElement = e.target;

   if(targetElement == document.getElementById("form")) {
      console.log("inside");
      return;
   } else {
      document.getElementById("main").style.display="none";
      console.log("outside");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pete — That is pretty much what the introductory paragraph of the question says.

Comment: Instead of adding all possible elements from the tree structure to check whether the event target was either of them specifically, you should use [`.contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/)  to figure out whether the target is “inside” your form or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to add the label and input elements to the 'if' statement in the JS function?

Yes, but the general implementation of a solution would be to get the target and then recursively check it's `parentNode`s until you found `document.getElementById("form"))` or ran out of parents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
function hide(e) {
    if (e.closest('#form')) {
        console.log("inside");
        return;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("main").style.display="none";
        console.log("outside");
    }
}
```